# SFINAE Why am I not detecting std::vector's subscript operator?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I've written some template-meta nonsense to detect if class methods exists.

The template struct `has_subscript` is specialized so that the second template parameter is `void` if the first template parameter has a subscript operator. If the subscript operator is found, the specialization is used, otherwise SFINAE defaults to the non-specialized version.

I have the code working for a simple struct foo (it's templated just to better match `std::vector`), but it unexpectedly fails with `std::vector`.

demo link https://godbolt.org/z/5-QzAp

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename>
struct void_wrap
{ using type = void; };


template <typename T, typename = void>
struct has_subscript
{
  static constexpr bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct has_subscript <T, typename void_wrap<typename result_of<decltype(&T::operator[])(T,int)>::type>::type >
{
  static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename T>
struct foo
{
  double operator[](size_t x){return 0.0;}
};

int main()
{
  cout << has_subscript<foo<int>>::value;
  cout << has_subscript<vector<int>>::value;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to do with how you are attempting to deduce the `operator[]`, it works for `foo` but not for `std::vector` because it is overloaded.

The expression `typename result_of<decltype(&T::operator[])(T,int)>::type` cannot be used since `&T::operator[]` is ambiguous.

If you use `decltype(std::declval<T&>()[int()])`, then it works as expected (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/DytDVW)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::is_detected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected) from the *library fundamentals TS v2*.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <experimental/type_traits>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
using bracket_op_t = decltype( std::declval<T&>()[0] );

template<typename T>
constexpr bool has_bracket_op = std::experimental::is_detected<bracket_op_t, T>::value;

int main()
{
    // static_assert(has_bracket_op<int>, ""); // fails to compile
    static_assert(has_bracket_op<std::vector<int>>, "");
}
```

### [LIVE DEMO](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/pIYg-f)

Comment: This is a handy workaround that I didn't know about, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: @roro I know, but at least it solves your problem, doesn't it? Are you bound to using your approach?

Comment: I'm bound to a c++14 compiler and can't introduce external dependencies.

Comment: @roro My code is C++14. Look at the compiler version and flags I was using. It is GCC 8.3 with `std=c++14`. You just have to include `<experimental/type_traits>`.